# Мигающий курсор

Tags: html, jquery, css, css3, вёрстка

Как сделать постоянно мигающий курсор в поле ввода `<input type='text'>` ?
Т.е. не зависимо от того, есть ли фокус в данном поле ввода.
При фокусе в поле ввода там появляется стандартное мигание курсора, но нужно чтобы и без фокуса было мигание

```
.form label:before{
    content: '';
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 14px;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index:3;
    animation: cursor 1s infinite ease;
}
.form label.cursor:before{
    display: inline-block;
}
@keyframes cursor {
    50%{
        background: transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: только имитировать его - `input + label:before`, 'animation'

Comment: Вам не кажется что это смутит пользователя, он будет думать что фокус находится на поле для ввода, начнет заполнять форму и окажется что ввод не происходит потому что фокус совершенно в другом месте.

Comment: С помощью js и jQuery написать функцию, меняющую cursor: default на cursor: none и обратно по таймеру

Comment: @Данила Никонец, а подробней можно? Получается, что нужно вызвать метод jquery `$(input).focus();` на поле ввода, а если пользователь наведёт курсор на другое поле ввода, то с предыдущего фокус пропадёт

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста, добавил анимацию, но теперь курсор исчезает плавно, а нужно чтобы курсор исчезал не плавно. Как это сделать?
https://jsfiddle.net/7576gmdj/

Comment: @Паша Иванов, это не моя прихоть, и полей не очень много

Comment: @word Я сначала не правильно понял, какой курсор должен мигать.
Чтобы исчезал не плавно поиграйте с кейфреймом и длительностью анимации.
Попробуйте так

keyframes cursor {
  0%{
        background: transparent;
  }
   49%{
        background: transparent;
   }
    50%{
        background: #000;
    }
    100%{
        background: #000;
    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Анимацию можно отключить по `step-end`.
+ нужно убирать свой курсор на фокусе, чтобы не пересекался с системным курсором. и еще нужно совсем его удалять на заполненном инпуте.

```css
.form label:before {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
}

.form input:not(:focus) + label.cursor:before {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: cursor 1s infinite step-end;
}

@keyframes cursor {
  50% { background: transparent; }
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
    <label class="cursor"></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел и переделал решение отсюда: https://benfrain.com/creating-a-custom-input-cursorcaret/

```js
// Communicate to DOM that we have JS

document.documentElement.setAttribute("class", "js");

var searchFauxInput = document.querySelector(".fb-Search_FauxInput");
var searchBox = document.getElementById("Input");

searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", function copyInput(event) {
      searchFauxInput.textContent = searchBox.value;
      searchBox.setAttribute("value", searchBox.value);
}, false);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.fb-Search {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 5px 70px 5px 5px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

.fb-Search_Input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
}

.js .fb-Search_Input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100vw;
}

.fb-Search_FauxInput {
    display: none;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    max-width: 80%;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
        color: #777;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}

.js .fb-Search_FauxInput {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.fb-Search_Input ~ .fb-Search_FauxInput {
    -webkit-animation: pulseAttention 1.5s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1) forwards infinite;
    animation: pulseAttention 1.5s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1) forwards infinite;
}

.fb-Search_Label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.fb-Search_Input:not([value=""]) ~ .fb-Search_Label {
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulseAttention {
    50% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}

@keyframes pulseAttention {
    50% {
        border-color: #000;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="fb-Search">
    <input id="Input" class="fb-Search_Input" value="">
    <span class="fb-Search_FauxInput" dir="rtl"></span>
    <label class="fb-Search_Label" for="Input">Search</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

если нужно чтобы пользователь что-то ввел сразу,  то можно попробовать `<input type= 'text' autofocus>`

**Upd:**

Хотя нет

> For better usability, avoid using autofocus. Automatically focusing on a form control can cause the page to scroll on load. The focus can also cause dynamic keyboards to display on some touch devices. While a screen reader will announce the label of the form control receiving focus, the screen reader will not announce anything before the label, and the sighted user on a small device will equally miss the context created by the preceding content.

Comment: хотя нет  For better usability, avoid using autofocus. Automatically focusing on a form control can cause the page to scroll on load. The focus can also cause dynamic keyboards to display on some touch devices. While a screen reader will announce the label of the form control receiving focus, the screen reader  will not announce anything before the label, and the sighted user on a small device will equally miss the context created by the preceding content.

Comment: Вы можете или [поправить ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1119062/edit), или его удалить. Писать комментарии самому себе не стоит.